# Displaying Grails Field Errors

Tags: grails, error-handling, grails-validation

Does anybody know how I could get the `fieldError` to print out in the example below.

for each item with an error, I would like to print custom error messages that I have defined in the messages.properties file

at the moment all this does is print the default error codes

```
item.errors?.allErrors?.each{ 
  println it.toString() 
}
```

I have seen other examples where you can lookup an error code for a field e.g.

```
it.getFieldError('title').code
```

but I would like to convert the default message into my new error message and print that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need access to the messageSource bean, e.g. with

```
def messageSource
```

in your controller or service. Then you can access the messages with

```
def locale = Locale.getDefault()
for (fieldErrors in bean.errors) {
   for (error in fieldErrors.allErrors) {
      String message = messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)
   }
}
```

Comment: put def messageSource (in controller or service)

Thanks this worked.

item.errors?.allErrors?.each{ 
println  messageSource.getMessage(it, null)
};


I also found a good link which explains this better

http://johnrellis.blogspot.com/2010/02/retrieve-grails-domain-errors-from.html

Comment: Burt, it doesn't seem like this become any more straightforward since 2010. Is there a reason that the individual error objects don't have a `message` field that returns the specific message rather than having to import a bean and call a static method?

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simplier solution with a better performance would be;

```
MessageSource messageSource //Inject the messageSource class

e.errors.allErrors.each {
  String message = messageSource.getMessage(it, Locale.default)
}
```

OR

If you want to deal only with field errors:

```
e.errors.fieldErrors.each {
   String message = messageSource.getMessage("modified.invalid.validator.message", [it.field, 'message'] as Object[], Locale.default))
}
```

Where `modified.invalid.validator.message` is the local string in your `messages.properties`. In this particular example, this message reads something like...

```
modified.invalid.validator.message=Property [{0}] of [{1}] does not pass validation
```